# Minimize a convex function subject to concave quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

I am looking into the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\Delta X}{\text{minimize}} & trace(\Delta X^H \Delta X)\\ \text{subject to} & (X+\Delta X)'Q(X + \Delta X) \succeq Q\end{array}$$

where $Q$ is a positive matrix (complex Hermitian), and $X$, $\Delta X$ are complex diagonal matrices.

What is the state of art in solving such problems? I am hoping for something simpler than the generic convex-concave procedure (CCP), e.g., the approach outlined in

- Xinyue Shen, Steven Diamond, Yuantao Gu, Stephen Boyd, [Disciplined Convex-Concave Programming](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1604.02639), April 2016.

Comment: What is the optimization variable?

Comment: How can you sum the matrix $X$ and the vector $\Delta X$?

Comment: What is the norm you are considering? Is is the 2-norm of the vector of diagonal entries or the induced 2-norm of the matrix $\Delta X$?

Comment: I would be tempted to conjecture that $\Delta X^*=X-I$. The reason is that the minimum will be attained on the boundary of the set defined by the inequality, which consists of an ellipse.